# Group policy not being applied to service account

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I made a small change to group policy under `Default Domain Policy` to ensure that all users shared the same regional settings with regards decimal points and date/time formats.

This appears to have worked fine for my account, as when I log in via remote desktop and check regional settings, everything is in order.

However, I have a service account running schedueled task every hour, and based on the output of these logs, I can see that the incorrect date format is still being used.

How can I ensure that the group policy change is applied ot this account?

Note that I am unable to log in using this account as it does not have remote desktop  access (and I am not sitting in front of the server). It is only used to run a scheduled task and nothing else.

Any advice is much appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide any additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group Policies applies to interactive logon only, take a look at my answer here:

https://serverfault.com/a/867366/318166

Comment: Thanks for your answer Swisstone. I noticed this morning that it appears that the settings were reset at around 11pm last night, so now the date format is wrong again. So I logged in as the service account again, and now the policy is being applied again (even after signing out again...) Do you happen to know why that would happen?

Comment: No, I don't know, but since it's not really supported you may experience these strange and unpredictable behaviours.
But, you can try to copy these settings in the default user profile: Control Panel -> Region -> "Administrative" tab and "Copy Settings".

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by temporarily adding the service account in question to the remote users list. AFter logging in via remote desktop, the group policy was applied and I can see from the application logs that the correct formats are now being used.